# Does pandas have any kind of size limit on filters?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

This is a weird question but I'm getting weird results. I have a dataframe containing data for college basketball games:

```
    game_id season  home_team   away_team   net_ortg    net_drtg    clock   period  home    visitor ... total_seconds_elapsed   win lead    p_1 p_2 p_3 p_4 p_5 p_6 total_pts
627168  401173715   2020    Air Force   UC Riverside    12.0    10.5    00:06:34    1   37  24  ... 806 1   13  1   0   0   0   0   0   61
320163  401174714   2020    Arkansas State  Idaho   11.4    0.4 00:01:42    2   76  67  ... 2298    1   9   0   1   0   0   0   0   143
26942   401169867   2020    Vanderbilt  Tulsa   1.5 10.9    00:07:50    1   24  18  ... 730 0   6   1   0   0   0   0   0   42
213142  401170184   2020    La Salle    Wagner  2.3 -13.5   00:10:19    2   57  36  ... 1781    1   21  0   1   0   0   0   0   93
1631866 401255594   2021    Virginia Tech   South Florida   8.4 -1.5    00:19:32    1   2   0   ... 28  1   2   1   0   0   0   0   0   2
1644302 401263600   2021    Nebraska    South Dakota    1.2 -8.1    00:14:51    1   9   11  ... 309 1   -2  1   0   0   0   0   0   20
1181057 401170704   2020    Colorado    Stanford    4.7 3.1 00:14:22    1   6   4   ... 338 1   2   1   0   0   0   0   0   10
1670578 401266749   2021    Texas Tech  Troy    15.2    -17.9   00:07:54    2   67  33  ... 1926    1   34  0   1   0   0   0   0   100
27199   401170392   2020    Florida Gulf Coast  Campbell    -5.6    -2.0    00:17:46    1   2   0   ... 134 0   2   1   0   0   0   0   0   2
1588187 401262682   2021    UNLV    Montana State   4.5 -0.8    00:02:54    1   23  39  ... 1026    0   -16 1   0   0   0   0   0   62
```

I am using `test_train_split` from sklearn to split the dataframe on `game_id` so I can do some ML tasks.

```
train_id, test_id = train_test_split(list(df.game_id), test_size=0.1)
train_mask = df['game_id'].isin(list(train_id))
test_mask = df['game_id'].isin(list(test_id))
print(df.shape)
print(len(train_id))
print(len(test_id))
>>(1326422, 22)
>>1193779
>>132643
```

Here's the weird thing (or at least the part I am not understanding):

```
>>train_mask.describe()
count     1326422
unique          1
top          True
freq      1326422
Name: game_id, dtype: object

>>test_mask.describe()
count     1326422
unique          1
top          True
freq      1326422
Name: game_id, dtype: object
```

Ok, but what if I do the exact same statement but limit the size of `train_id`:

```
train_mask = df['game_id'].isin(list(train_id[0:100]))
train_mask.describe()
count     1326422
unique          2
top         False
freq      1302107
Name: game_id, dtype: object
```

And just to check again using array indexing on the full list:

```
train_mask = df['game_id'].isin(list(train_id[0:-1]))
train_mask.describe()
count     1326422
unique          1
top          True
freq      1326422
Name: game_id, dtype: object
```

For the life of me I can't figure out what is going on unless there is some limitation on the size of the queries that pandas is able to run. Help!

Edit: It appears the exact size where this behavior happens is 54,665:

```
>>train_mask = df['game_id'].isin(list(train_id[0:54665]))
>>train_mask.describe()
count     1326422
unique          2
top          True
freq      1326180
Name: game_id, dtype: object

>>train_mask = df['game_id'].isin(list(train_id[0:54666]))
>>train_mask.describe()
count     1326422
unique          1
top          True
freq      1326422
Name: game_id, dtype: object
```

Truly bizarre!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `game_id` is not a unique identifier, you may be ending up with the same `game_id`s in both your train and test set, which is likely resulting in the same records ending up in both the train and test set. Instead, created a train_test_split on unique game_ids.

```
train_id, test_id = train_test_split(df.game_id.unique(), test_size=0.1)
```

Comment: Sorry, yeah, it was not a unique identifier. So that was causing the problem. I needed to split on unique ids.

Comment: That's really helpful information - updated my answer based on what may be your true issue.

Answer (score 3):

`pd.Series.isin` returns a Boolean Series the same length of whatever you were checking. So you won't change the shape of anything until you slice your DataFrame: `df_train = df[train_mask]`

To clarify a few things, the output of `describe` displays the following:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([True]*10 + [False]*6)

s.describe()
#count       16    # length of the Series
#unique       2    # Number of unique values in the Series
#top       True    # Most common value
#freq        10    # How many times does the most common value appear
#dtype: object
```

So checking for different IDs will never change the count. But unique, top and freq are all changing to reflect the fact that your mask itself changes.

Comment: The count is not changing but look at the frequency and distinct count of values I posted. It doesn’t make sense.

Comment: @EvanZamir I can almost guarantee the issue is not with pandas imposing any limit and instead is due to a misunderstanding of the data, or how a method is working. For instance if `game_id` is heavily duplicated in your DataFrame, then the way your are sampling it's likely the same game_id appears both in the train and test sets. I.e. maybe you want something like `train_test_split(df.game_id.unique().tolist(), 0.1)`

Comment: Ah! Yup, that is the issue. I'm dumb lol.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that what's going on is that your mask is a set of `True` `False` values that are the length of the DataFrame. When you are limiting the size of `train_id`, you are just reducing the number of `True` values rather than decreasing the length of the mask. Try the following to confirm:

```
print(len(df['game_id'].isin(list(train_id[0:100]))))
print(len(df['game_id'].isin(list(train_id[0:-1]))))
```

And then to see how many true values you have (sum works here because True is evaluated as a 1 and False as a 0):

```
df['game_id'].isin(list(train_id[0:100])).sum()
df['game_id'].isin(list(train_id[0:-1])).sum()
```

Comment: When I try to use the mask to filter the df, it doesn't work. That's the problem. It just keeps all the rows. When I do `df[df['game_id'].isin(list(train_id))].shape` it gives the same exact shape as the df itself.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just adding on to ALollz's solution, to show you the dataframes (so accept his/her answer). As stated, this will return a series of True and False:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
[['401173715',   '2020',    'Air Force'],   
['401174714' ,  '2020',    'Arkansas State'],  
['401169867' ,  '2020',    'Vanderbilt'],
['401170184'  , '2020',    'La Salle'],
['401255594'  , '2021',    'Virginia Tech'],
['401263600'  , '2021',    'Nebraska'],
['401170704'  , '2020',    'Colorado'],
['401266749'  , '2021',    'Texas Tech'],
['401170392'  , '2020',    'Florida Gulf'],
['401262682'  , '2021',    'UNLV']],
columns = ['game_id', 'season',  'home_team'   ])
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

train_id, test_id = train_test_split(list(df.game_id), test_size=0.1)


train_mask = df['game_id'].isin(list(train_id))
test_mask = df['game_id'].isin(list(test_id))
```

[image]

So the description is right as ALollz describes. Has 2 unique values (True, False), and the top value counts are either True or False, depending which mask you are looking at, and count are same, and frequency will change. now if you limit the rows and not include the last row (index 10), you're left with only 1 unique value in each data set.

Now what I am assuming what you want is to actually get those rows (where it's True). So you need to change the syntax to:

```
train_mask = df[df['game_id'].isin(list(train_id))]
test_mask = df[df['game_id'].isin(list(test_id))]
```

This will give you the 2 dataframes with the train_ids and the test ids:

[image]

So play with this code to see:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
[['401173715',   '2020',    'Air Force'],   
['401174714' ,  '2020',    'Arkansas State'],  
['401169867' ,  '2020',    'Vanderbilt'],
['401170184'  , '2020',    'La Salle'],
['401255594'  , '2021',    'Virginia Tech'],
['401263600'  , '2021',    'Nebraska'],
['401170704'  , '2020',    'Colorado'],
['401266749'  , '2021',    'Texas Tech'],
['401170392'  , '2020',    'Florida Gulf'],
['401262682'  , '2021',    'UNLV']],
columns = ['game_id', 'season',  'home_team'   ])
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

train_id, test_id = train_test_split(list(df.game_id), test_size=0.1)


train_mask = df['game_id'].isin(list(train_id))
test_mask = df['game_id'].isin(list(test_id))

df_train = df[train_mask]
df_test = df[test_mask]
```

Comment: That is exactly what I’m doing. It doesn’t work when I use the entire data frame.

Comment: what version of pandas you on?

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake, not pandas. I needed to do `df.game_id.unique()`, since what must have been happening is that the same ids were being sampled in train and test. My bad!

Comment: Ah gotcha. Cool.